# Match using a variable and return complete word

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, string-matching

So what I am trying to do is, create a regex where I can match  the first letter of a word using a variable (for example: "A") and then get every word which starts with an A (for example: "Albert")

to make this more clear:

```
var str = "Albert Alfonso Aladin Brianna Betina";
var txtValue = "A";
var regex = new RegExp(txtValue, "g");
var found = str.match(regex);
```

The output I am trying to achieve is:

--> if str = A, output: "Albert Alfonso Aladin"

--> if str = B, output: "Brianna Betina"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9052177/3832970, `new RegExp('\\b' + txtValue + '\\w*','g')` looks to be what you need.

Comment: thank you very much, havent seen that question sorry!